# Wierd double-click or folder navigation sound in Windows 7 while system is idle

Tags: windows-7, audio, malware

Hi I am having a similar problem as found [in this question](https://superuser.com/questions/495882/i-hear-clicks-in-the-speakers-but-i-did-not-click-anything) and definitely [not this one](https://superuser.com/questions/344790/weird-sound-in-windows-7)

- The time interval/pattern of navigation sounds I hear from the speaker is two continuous folder traversing sounds after a pause of about 1second again 1 click sound and hear this sound for some exact time periods like every one hour(12.36pm, 01:36pm, 2.37pm,...6.38pm.. etc).
- I confirmed this by changing the folder navigation sound in my windows Control Panel Sound settings. Under the sound tab I changed the Start Navigation sound from default to ding.wav and I hear the same ding.wav navigation sound from the speakers.
- I have a McAfee Antivirus installed in my PC. Wouldn't that deleted any malwares entering my system? However sometimes virus named like Artermis virus gets deleted by my antivirus I don't know where it is generated from.
- I'm not using IE browser which can be an issue like the [one mentioned here](https://superuser.com/questions/55956/what-causes-random-clicking-navigation-sound-while-pc-is-idle). But my Chrome and Firefox are open all the time for my browsing. I'm not sure that will be an issue eventhough FF and Chrome may use IE settings to connect to internet.

Comment: My wife's laptop does this, it annoys the hell out of me. Do you leave a CNN tab open?

Comment: no i don't..i mostly keep FB or SO tabs open in my chrome browser..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the problem seems to be in some kind of adware/malware that I had in my system through browsers. I was not able to track down what exact extension/software was causing this issue.

But, I installed [AdwCleaner](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/adwcleaner/) which cleaned up my system of all unwanted adware's and it worked perfectly. I'm no more hearing the sound anymore.